# Ghost error in Visual Studio - "missing definition" coming from nowhere

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I've got a windows store app which I've been working on for months now.

This afternoon I tried to use visual studio remote debugger to test the app on an ARM tablet. I didn't get as far as the debugging stage, because my build threw the following error.

```
Error 153   'MyApp.Editor' does not contain a definition for 'OneDriveUpload_Click' 
            and no extension method 'OneDriveUpload_Click' accepting a first argument 
            of type 'MyApp.Editor' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
            or an assembly reference?)  
            C:\Users\Rory\Dropbox\MyApp\Editor.xaml 517 91  MyApp
```

When I double click this error in the error list, it takes me to line 517 of Editor.xaml:

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="View HTML Source" Click="HTMLSource_Click" Style="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutItemStyle_HTML}" />
```

There was a reference to `OneDriveUpload_Click` here some weeks back, but it's long gone. I've done a search for `OneDriveUpload` throughout my solution and only got one hit for a piece of commented out code.

Where the heck is this coming from?

This is not the first "ghost" error I've seen. Every time my app fails to compile, for whatever reason, I also have the following two errors.

```
Error   151 The name "BasePrintPage" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyApp".
```

Except it definitely does:

```
namespace MyApp
{
   public class BasePrintPage : Page
   { 
       ....
   }
}
```

I also get an error telling me

```
Error   152 The member "BottomAppBar" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

If there are no other errors, the project compiles without issue, so these are not "real" errors. How do I get rid of them, and the one that's stopping me from compiling?

EDIT: Just thought I'd add that deleting the SUO file has no effect on these issues.

Comment: did you previously have a different version of the app installed on the tablet?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to contact Dropbox for support.  Then again, by the time you hear back from them, the proper file would probably have arrived.

Comment: @HansPassant why do you say that?

Comment: Because your project is stored in a Dropbox folder.  Don't do that.

Comment: @DrewJordan yes, but it has compiled as recently as an hour ago with no issue.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see how that makes any difference. My files get synced up to dropbox when changed, so what?

Comment: I get a lot of errors like this: `Error   151 The name "BasePrintPage" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyApp".` in some of my WPF projects if I open up the xaml code.  From what I can gather it seems to be an issue with the designer not able to resolve some namespace references, since even with those errors present it still builds successfully and if I close the xaml file they instantly disappear

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing the "offending" line, saving the file, compiling, then undoing the change, re-saving it again and re-compiling. I don't feel like accepting this answer though as it doesn't *explain* what the heck just happened, or resolve my long standing false errors with `BottomAppBar` et al.

I'm guessing I'll just have to put this down to another quirk of Visual Studio